# unable to use deprecated class in the latest build of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am working through a newsapp android studio app project and unable to resolve the unused / deprecation error for Preferences class.

[Please see the screenshot in this link for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecl9J.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File > Setting > Editor > Inspection** and uncheck the inspection which you dont want to perform.